# How long do wild seeds take to grow?

Tags: stardew-valley

The end of spring is coming up, and I don't want to waste any of my spring seeds (wild seeds) on crops that will die before being harvestable. How many days do they take to grow/what is the last day I can plant them and still get a harvest?

Comment: I feel silly asking this since I could have just paid attention while getting my foraging to lvl 10, but I didn't, and somehow neither wiki lists the grow time for wild seeds. EDIT, it's listed, just not on the wild seeds own page... it's seven days..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wild seeds, whatever what they will give you in the end, will always take seven days to grow up, as you said. It is confirmed in the [Stardew Valley Wiki Crops' page](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crops#Wild_Seeds) :

> Regardless of what ends up growing, wild seeds all take the same
>   amount of time to grow to maturity (7 days, not counting the day
>   planted).

Answer (score 2):

This information is directly from the [Stardew Valley Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crops#Wild_Seeds)

> Wild Seeds can be crafted out of foraged plants once you reach the
>   appropriate foraging level (Spring at level 1, Summer at level 4, Fall
>   at level 6, Winter at level 7). Each recipe will produce 10 seed
>   packets. When planted, wild seeds will randomly grow into one of that
>   season's foraged plants. Regardless of what ends up growing, wild
>   seeds all take the same amount of time to grow to maturity (7 days,
>   not counting the day planted).